# with polars, how do you use conditionals with lazyframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

i tried to use lazyframes, but it seems there are a lot of limitations.

for example, i have a list comprehension which runs a function on an expression x

```
final = [
    df.select(
        threshold_rank(λ=lambda_df.select(series + '_lambda').item(),
                       x=pl.col(series))
        .alias(series + '_rank')
    ).collect()
    for series in fields
]
```

i'm supposed to get back a lazyframe:

```
def threshold_rank(λ, x):
    e = 2.718281828459045
    t = 22.108576145  # t is the threshold value
    k = 1  # k is a scaling factor that determines how rapidly the rankings increase above the threshold
    if x <=t:
        calc = 10 - ((10 - 1) / t) * (t - x)
    else:
        calc = 10 - (9 * e ** (-λ * (x - t)))
    return calc
```

i get:

```
File "C:\Users\calcs.py", line 91, in threshold_rank
    if x.le(t).is_in(True):
  File "C:\Users\\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\polars\expr\expr.py", line 193, in __bool__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Since Expr are lazy, the truthiness of an Expr is ambiguous. Hint: use '&' or '|' to logically combine Expr, not 'and'/'or', and use 'x.is_in([y,z])' instead of 'x in [y,z]' to check membership.
```

i've tried to do something like:

if `x.le(t)`: but this is still no good.

so, really confused about first: when is it a good idea to use lazyframes vs not.

and second how to solve this problem

update:
tried the following:

```
def threshold_rank(λ, x, series):
    e = 2.718281828459045
    t = 22.108576145  # t is the threshold value
    k = 1  # k is a scaling factor that determines how rapidly the rankings increase above the threshold
    calc = pl.when(
        x.le(t).any()
        .then(10 - ((10 - 1) / t) * (t - x))
        .otherwise(10 - (9 * e ** (-λ * (x - t))))
    )
    return calc
```

but i get     `.then(10 - ((10 - 1) / t) * (t - x)) AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'then'`

update 2:

ok this should have been solved by simply noticing the parenthesis:

`when().then().otherwise()`

but i will leave this open to anyone who has advice on improving the use of lazyframes/expressions

Comment: Hi @rnd om, can you share a minimum reproducible example for the df and lambda_df dataframe? ideally in the format `pl.DataFrame()`

also- does it work on dataframe ? so you only have a problem with lazyframes?

Comment: @Luca hey thanks for the response, it's really with lazyframes - and i think it's because i'm not understanding the how these expressions work.. i will edit to add another update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example would be helpful, it looks like you have something like:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
   {
      "a": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
      "b": [4, 5, 6, 7], 
   }
).lazy()

df_lambda = pl.DataFrame(
   {
      "a_lambda": [4, 3, 2, 1], 
      "b_lambda": [7, 6, 5, 4]
   }
).lazy()
```

For which you could use:

```
#e = 2.718281828459045
t = 22.108576145

fields = "a", "b"

df.with_context(df_lambda).with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col(name) <= t)
     .then(
        10 - ((10 - 1) / t) * (t - pl.col(name)))
     .otherwise(
        10 - (9 * (-(pl.col(f"{name}_lambda") * (pl.col(name) - t))).exp()))
     .alias(f"{name}_rank") 
   for name in fields
).collect()
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_rank   ┆ b_rank   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 1.407082 ┆ 2.628327 │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 1.814164 ┆ 3.035409 │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 2.221246 ┆ 3.442491 │
│ 4   ┆ 7   ┆ 2.628327 ┆ 3.849573 │
└─────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

polars also has [`.exp()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.exp.html) which can replace the manual approach [as suggested by @DeanMacGregor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796307/with-polars-how-do-you-use-conditionals-with-lazyframes/75801859?noredirect=1#comment133714358_75801859)

Comment: I would encourage OP not to manually do the exponential but rather replace `e ** (-(pl.col(f"{name}_lambda") * (pl.col(name) - t)))` with `(-(pl.col(f"{name}_lambda") * (pl.col(name) - t))).exp()`